# How to insert AWS resource IDs into application configuration files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following the AWS guide for deploying an HA Wordpress site to Elastic Beanstalk which includes using the `eb-php-wordpress` extension. The process requires editing a couple of configuration files with known resource IDs prior to deploying the application.

In particular, the instructions say to edit the `efs-create.config` file with a VPC ID, and Subnet IDs. The file, among other things, helps set the `OptionSettings` property of the `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment` resource. For this reason, I suspect I should just be able to reference it with `Ref:`. Is this correct, though since the VPC would be created by another file and the EB environment Cloudformation stack is created next to the VPC stack rather than "inside" it? Would I have to use a `Fn::` call to get the information?

The section of the configuration file I'm working with looks like this:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption:
    EFSVolumeName: "EB-EFS-Volume"
    VPCId: "vpc-XXXXXXXX"
## Subnet Options
    SubnetA: "subnet-XXXXXXXX"
    SubnetB: "subnet-XXXXXXXX"
    SubnetC: "subnet-XXXXXXXX"
    SubnetD: "subnet-XXXXXXXX"
```

Would the VPCId line be something like

```
VPCId: {Ref: VPC}
```

Where `VPC` is the name of the VPC resource that I've created? Or, more simply, how would I reference the VPC ID of the default VPC if I stick with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `Ref` to get the various IDs of the elastic beanstalk [named resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-format-resources-eb.html), according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html#ebextensions-functions-ref). However, the VPC is not one of these named resources (ie those with a logical ID), but *is* a *property* of one of the named resources, in this case, the logical ID is `AWSEBSecurityGroup` and the property is `VpcId` so you should be able to get it instead using `GetAtt`:

`{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AWSEBSecurityGroup", "VpcId" ] }`

from the [functions docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html#ebextensions-functions-getatt) and the [CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#w2ab1c21c10d112d104c13)

A similar approach should also work for the subnets.

Comment: Nice. Thank you. This will work if I create a new VPC or use an existing one, yes?

Comment: Follow-up: The AWSEBV2LoadBalancer resource has an array of subnets rather than each being identified individually. Am I correct in thinking that in this case I would use `Fn::Select` to assign each subnet ID to one of the lines in my question?

Comment: Perhaps as `{ "Fn::Select" : [ "0", [ { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AWSEBLoadBalancer", "Subnets" ] ] }`