# How to reference the the AWSEBV2LoadBalancer Subnets property?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following the AWS guide for deploying an HA Wordpress site to Elastic Beanstalk which includes using the eb-php-wordpress extension. The process requires editing a couple of configuration files with known resource IDs prior to deploying the application.

In particular, the instructions say to edit the efs-create.config file with a VPC ID, and Subnet IDs. The file, among other things, helps set the OptionSettings property of the AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment resource. Thanks to [danimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55655096/1602022), I now know how to pull the VpcId into the file using `Fn::GetAtt`:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption:
    EFSVolumeName: "EB-EFS-Volume"
    VPCId: { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AWSEBSecurityGroup", "VpcId" ] }
  ## Subnet Options
    SubnetA: "subnet-XXXXXXXX"
    SubnetB: "subnet-XXXXXXXX"
    SubnetC: "subnet-XXXXXXXX"
    SubnetD: "subnet-XXXXXXXX"
```

Now my obstacle is getting those subnet IDs added. I tried applying the same, but slightly expanded, concept to the `AWSEBV2LoadBalancer` resource to pull the Subnets array, but I got an error.

The code:

```
SubnetA: { "Fn::Select" : [ "0", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AWSEBV2LoadBalancer", "Subnets" ] } ] }
SubnetB: { "Fn::Select" : [ "1", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AWSEBV2LoadBalancer", "Subnets" ] } ] }
SubnetC: { "Fn::Select" : [ "2", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AWSEBV2LoadBalancer", "Subnets" ] } ] }
SubnetD: { "Fn::Select" : [ "3", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AWSEBV2LoadBalancer", "Subnets" ] } ] }
```

The error:

```
 Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template error: resource AWSEBV2LoadBalancer does not support attribute type Subnets in Fn::GetAtt
```

I found this odd since the generated template shows `Subnets` under that resouce :

```
"AWSEBV2LoadBalancer": {
    "Properties": {
        "SecurityGroups": [
            {
                "Ref": "AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup"
            }
        ],
        "Subnets": [
            "subnet-0ec0699f08ff45e6e",
            "subnet-0a4fec611d42b062f",
            "subnet-09a4c28b8f330c0c3",
            "subnet-0ea8d69e46ce87afc"
        ]
    },
    "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer"
},
```

I also tried assigning the array using `Subnets: { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "AWSEBV2LoadBalancer", "Subnets" ]` and then using `Fn::Select` and `Ref` on that: `SubnetA: { "Fn::Select" : [ "0", [ "Ref" : "Subnets" ] ] }` but that created its own error:

```
Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [Subnets] in the Resources block of the template
```

How do I extract that array and assign each element to a different resource?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html - the AWSEBV2LoadBalancer has no GetAtt for subnets :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the docs (per danimal), this is not possible. Leaves me wondering how others have done it as I can't imagine I'm the first to try.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is needed for someone as I spent a bit of time to figure out how to have dynamic values in ebextension file when mounting EFS in different environments.
If you are using Cloud Formation template to create your resources you can set all option settings in CloudFormation template itself, there you will have references to VPCId and Subnets and then use defined option settings in mount script.

```
MyElasticBeanstalkEnvironment:
  Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
  Properties:
    ...
    OptionSettings:
      ...
      - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption'
        OptionName: 'VPCId'
        Value: !Ref VpcId
      - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption'
        OptionName: 'SubnetA'
        Value: !Select [ 0, !Ref SubnetIds ]
      - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption'
        OptionName: 'SubnetB'
        Value: !Select [ 1, !Ref SubnetIds ]
      - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:customoption'
        OptionName: 'SubnetC'
        Value: !Select [ 2, !Ref SubnetIds ]
```

You can either pass them to CF template as parameters or in case you create your VPC in this template you will be able to reference your resource.

Just make sure that parameter names are the same as in your ebextension

```
  ...
  MountTargetA:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: {Ref: FileSystem}
      SecurityGroups:
        - {Ref: MountTargetSecurityGroup}
      SubnetId:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting: {OptionName: SubnetA}
  ...
```